# React ESLint is still throwing no-unused-expressions with optional chainging

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a function call that uses optional chaining

```
const index = [1, 2, 3, 4]
media.name?.forEach((m) => {
   if (index.includes(m)) {
      console.log('Found index');
    }
  });
```

The ESLint shows the warning for this line as:

`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

I checked with this issue [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12822). As they pointed in the end, the issue has been closed and `no-unused-expressions` rule will support optional chaining.

Why am I still seeing this warning in my code?

My eslint config file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": [],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react-hooks", "react"],
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
    "react/prop-types": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: First, what exactly `media.name` is? Is it an array? Second, where is this `name` variable coming from in the `if` statement? Post all your relevant code, please.

Comment: @zhulien I don't think it matters, if the code in the question is sufficient to demonstrate the issue being asked about

Comment: I edited the code in the question, however, like @CertainPerformance said, I don't think the code inside matters. The problem is using a method after an optional chaining variable will cause this warning.